# When people say calculate moving average for 30 days include weekends or not?

Tags: moving-average

When someone wants to calculate a 30-day moving average of a commodity, do they mean 30 business days, or 30 calendar days?  I'm looking for the general consensus, not "you could do it this way or that way".

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=moving+average

Comment: IMHO this is a valid question for newbies.

Comment: why do you guys feel the need to be the smartest person in the room? this is a good question.  i found it through google.

Answer (score 6):

Trading days..................

Days where there is pricing information.

Any moving average is a moving average of pricing information. Not the times where there can be no pricing information.